# Durable Orchestrator gets stuck after Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an orchestrator with 4 activites:

1. **PromoDataFromActpm** - single activity that downloads some data
   from API.
2. **PromoDataExport** - single activity that sends data from activity #1
   to Azure Storage
3. **SavePromoProductFromACPSActivity** - Parallel activities, that for
   each item from activity #1 make a call to some API and downloads
   some data
4. **TableToBlobPromoProductActivity** - Parallel activities that write
   items from activity #3 to blob storage

For activities #3 each item in collection is 1 activity call, for activity #4 it is batched in collection of 50 items per 1 activity call, which are being awaited by Task.WhenAll.

Everything is working fine on local environment, but on azure, orchestrator stops processing after activity #3 Task.WhenAll for some reason.
I get many Requests for **SavePromoProductFromACPSActivity** in logs, as it should be, but after some time they stop and **TableToBlobPromoProductActivity** activity is never called. I just get occasionally "Executing XYZ orchestrator", and after few minutes "Executed XYZ orchestrator", with no activity calls between those messages.

I've been fighting with it for a while but without success. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
            var orchestrationId = context.InstanceId.Replace(":","");

            var promoData = await context.CallActivityAsync<PromotionExportModel[]>(FunctionNamesExport.Activity.PromoDataFromActpm, null);
            var exportResult = await context.CallActivityAsync<OperationResponse>(FunctionNamesExport.Activity.PromoDataExport, promoData);

            var acpsTasks = new List<Task<List<PromotedProductExportModel>>>();
            var acpsPromos = new List<PromotedProductExportModel>();
            foreach (var promo in promoData)
            {
                acpsTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<List<PromotedProductExportModel>>(FunctionNamesExport.Activity.SavePromoProductFromACPSActivity, promo));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(acpsTasks);
            acpsTasks.ForEach(x => acpsPromos.AddRange(x.Result));

            var promoDataBatched = acpsPromos.Batch(50);
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach(var arr in promoDataBatched)
            {
                var promoBlob = new PromotionExportSubModel
                {
                    PromotionExportModel = arr.ToArray(),
                    blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()),
                    orchestrationId = orchestrationId
                };
tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync(FunctionNamesExport.Activity.TableToBlobPromoProductActivity, promoBlob));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: How many activities does the orchestrator run in parallel?

Comment: @juunas as many as service plan P2v2 allows, so that would be 2 as there are 2 cores in this plan

Comment: Have you considered the new (.NET 6) [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) method instead of the `Task.WhenAll`? The former allows to control the degree of parallelism, and also in case of errors it fails fast (which is a good thing).

Comment: That wouldn't work in Durable Functions.

Comment: @Wolwgang I mean since you are running a batch of 50 for the last part, I assume the original list is quite a lot bigger than 2? How many times do you call the "SavePromoProductFromACPSActivity" activity in one orchestrator run?

Comment: Are you sure all the `SavePromoProductFromACPSActivity` activities are completing?

Comment: @juunas there are around 3k items that running in SavePromoProductFromACPSActivity, so around 3k Tasks, in logs I see that around 2k tasks for this activity are being completed, and then nothing. I'll try to reduce the number of them,  'cause maybe this is the issue

Comment: @StephenCleary like in comment above, only abound 2k of them from 3k are being requested in logs, and after that nothing. I also do not get any errors, I'm gonna try to reduce number of requests and see what happens then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in the comments you mentioned you are launching 3000 activities in parallel in step 3, I have one idea what could be happening.
Remember that each activity will add rows to the history table that all need to be loaded on each replay of the orchestrator (which occurs after each activity returns).
So the load time will keep going up and up, as well as memory usage.

A typical solution that I've used for this is to split the work into sub-orchestrators.
Break the data into batches of 100 for example, launch a sub-orchestrator for each of them to run in parallel.
Then in that sub-orchestrator do the actual step 3 activities.
This way that sub-orchestrator's instances' history table rows are capped at the required ones for 100 activities and the main orchestrator only gets ~30 results.
You can do a similar thing for step 4.